# Send TCP data to specfic TcpClient in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm getting an error that the TcpClient isn't connected and I can't send information to a socket that is not active. I'm wondering what's wrong with this code?
ERROR: This type of connection is not allowed on non-connected sockets.

```
SERVER:
public List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();

  On client connection:
  Socket s = currClient.Client;
  clients.Add(currClient.Client);

When Sending Client Info
   Stream sendData = clients[0].GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding text = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] clientInfoByte = text.GetBytes("msg");
        sendData.Write(clientInfoByte, 0, clientInfoByte.Length);
        sendData.Close();
```

CLIENT:

```
        Thread thr = new Thread(commands);
        thr.Start();
    }
    public static void commands()
    {
        Stream cmds = me.GetStream();
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            Socket s = me.Client;
            int k = s.Receive(b);
            string ClientInfo = "";
            string command = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);

            if (command == "msg")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Command Recieved!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more info. What is `currClient`? What's the address/bindings used on the sockets?

Comment: currClient is the current TCPClient (it gets named on connnection)

Answer (score 0):

In your server create a TcpListener "listener" and accept incoming connections using:

```
listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(
    new AsyncCallback(DoAcceptTcpClientCallback), 
    listener);
```

Then in your callback you get your TcpClient to send data to

```
// Process the client connection.       
public static void DoAcceptTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
    TcpListener listener = (TcpListener) ar.AsyncState;

    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);

    //add to your client list
    clients.Add(client);
  }
```

Comment: This didn't work. I'm getting an error about how I can't block a call on a socket.

Comment: Change Client.Blocking Property to false. From MSDN: "If you are in blocking mode, and you make a method call which does not complete immediately, your application will block execution until the requested operation completes. If you want execution to continue even though the requested operation is not complete, change the Blocking property to false."

Comment: Same error! I added s.Blocking = false; and it's still giving me the error saying that I'm blocking.